# Selenium Webdriver: Specify filepath for Firefox exe

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver

Can someone advise me on how to set the path for the firefox exe file in Selenium (C#).

I'm using the following code presently, however it is not working as hoped:

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

 profile.SetPreference("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

 IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use FirefoxBinary instead of FirefoxProfile as below

```java
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path/to/binary"));

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(binary);

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: This doesn't build for me, there is no ctor in FirefoxDriver that takes a FirefoxBinary argument. Also, your string is incorrectly quoted.

Comment: A little update about this answer, using the ctor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary, FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile) is obsolete. Instead use FirefoxOptions to setup the driver and pass the object to the ctor FirefoxDriver
`ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
ffOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Firefox\App\Firefox\firefox.exe";            
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOptions);`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to configure the system property.

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.firefox.bin", 'path/to/binary');